# I'm trying to make a string accept only letters and space BUT NO NUMBERS

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

This is what I theorized it should be but it seemed like it doesn't work.
HELP PLEAZEE

```
    int main()
    {
       char input[50];
       int i;

    do{
      printf("ENTER A CHARACTER:");
      scanf("%s",&input);

    if(isalpha(input)!=0){
       printf("YOU INPUTTED A CHARACTER");
       i++;
    }else{
       printf("INVALID INPUT\n");
    }

    }while(i!=1);

    }
```

Comment: should I just use isdigit instead of isalpha? but I think the result is the same its just the other way around.

Comment: Script? C is no scripting language....

Comment: `scanf("%s",&input);` --> `scanf("%49s",input);`

Comment: `int i;` --> `int i = 0;`

Comment: 1) Initialize `i = 0` 2. Scanf for a char - `scanf("%c", &input[i]);` 3. Check only the current char: `if (isalpha(input[i])) {` 4. After the loop, terminate string: `input[i] = '\0';`

Comment: Title is incorrect. By characters do you mean Alphabet ? Because numbers (digits) are also characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

isalpha takes an integer as an argument.
You are giving a char array.

You should loop for the number of characters given in input[], if you want more than one character (hard to tell from this code).
This exits if you give exactly one character but keeps going if you give more than one:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char input[50];
    int i = 0, j;
    size_t len = 0;

    do
    {
        printf("ENTER A CHARACTER:");
        scanf("%s",&input);

        len = strlen(input);

        for(j = 0; j < len; j++) {
            if(isalpha(input[j]))
            {
                i++;
                printf("YOU INPUTTED A CHARACTER %d\n", i);
            } 
            else 
            {
                printf("INVALID INPUT\n");
                break;
            }
        }
    } while(i!=1);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure about int len; ? Do you know what strlen returns? Take a look at [Strlen](http://www.stdlib.net/~colmmacc/strlen.c.html)

Comment: yes, it returns size_t. int is harmless as long as there won't be any negative values but thanks for pointing it out.